Error: "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hyperion057/spring-repo.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com" issue i trying to push to git
Error: "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hyperion057/spring-repo.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com"  having the issue trying to push to git how to fix
Tried generating a new token key but still is not working, also tried cloning the repo but still not working.

Do you mean ssh key?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
